# viewing contact details with Intent

Tags: android

i have created a small program to view Contact Names and Number in a list view .

```
public class showcontacts extends Activity
{
    ListView lv;
    Uri u;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listcontacts);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new mysellisten());
    u=Phone.CONTENT_URI;


    shownames();
}


public void shownames()
{
     String[] p=new String[] {  
                Contacts._ID,
             Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
             Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
             Phone.NUMBER

           };
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
+ ("1") + "' and "+ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER+"='1'" ;
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
+ " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(u, p, selection,null, sortOrder);
String from[]=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
int id[]={R.id.name,R.id.phoneno};
SimpleCursorAdapter sc=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.phoneview, c, from, id);

lv.setAdapter(sc);

}


class mysellisten implements OnItemClickListener
{


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri nu=ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, arg3);
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,nu);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

phoneview is a simple xml with Imageview and 2 textviews.
I am able to get the names and phonenos.However on clicking the item in the listview the record being shown is not proper.It does not match the record that i click. Some of the records dont even open the emulator returns back to the listview after showing a blank screen.

Also why is it that i am able to use Contacts table columns when i am using Phone.CONTENT_URI but if use the Contacts.CONTENT_URI i am not able to use the field Phone.NUMBER.
KINDLY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

have you add contacts `permission` to AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely retrive contact names and phone number using `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` please find the code  that does it

```
try {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            String name = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if ("1".equals(hasPhone) || Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) {
                // You know it has a number so now query it like this
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String dname = cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    System.out.println("Name is " + dname);
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    System.out.println("Phone Number is " + phoneNumber);
                    int itype = phones
                            .getInt(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                    final boolean isMobile = itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE
                            || itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE;


                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: my question is not how to get this data but why my code is working like this and if possible answer the bottom part